# Как сбросить пароль root в CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos

Как сбросить пароль рута в Centos 7? В инструкциях пишется отредактировать параметры загрузки, но у меня нет нужной строки, как быть?

Как должно быть -
[image: как должно быть, по инструкции]

Как у меня -

[image: и как у меня]

Comment: Пролистайте вниз, может быть, нужные вам строчки не влезли в экран? Если то, что вы показали -- всё содержимое записи загрузки, то система даже не должна грузиться в принципе.

Comment: @5anya точно, спасибо